# Numba CUDA reduce into array

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba

I have two reasonably large arrays of lengths N and M elements respectively. For each of the N elements I need to do a calculation with each of the M elements and then reduce these results in order to arrive at another array of length N. This sounds like the type of problem that is perfectly suited to GPU acceleration and I would therefore like to implement it using Numba CUDA, but I am struggling to find out how to deal with the reduction part of this problem. The Numba documentation on reduction https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/reduction.html only shows how everything can be reduced into one number, but I essentially need to reduce into an array. Below is a super simplified example of basically what I want to achieve

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def processArr(A, B):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < A.size:
        A[i] = A[i] * B

@cuda.jit
def reduceArr(A, B, C):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < A.size:
        total = 1
        processArr(A[i], B[i])

        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            total *= A[i, j]

        C[i] = total

a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
c = np.zeros(3)

threadsperblock = 32
blockspergrid = math.ceil(b.shape[0] / threadsperblock)

reduceArr[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](a, b, c)
print(c)
```

This code obviously does not run but hopefully it illustrates what I want to achieve.

Is there a way to achieve this with Numba or is it silly to try and do the reduction step on the GPU in the first place i.e. is it best to just do the NxM operations on the GPU and then reduce these results on the CPU afterwards?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with numba.  what are the actual sizes of `N` and `M`?  For the sizes you have shown here, it wouldn't make any sense to do any of this on the GPU.  And depending on the actual size of `N`, it may be more convenient to choose one of several different strategies.

Comment: the use of A.size is probably wrong

Comment: @RobertCrovella the real N is in the order of 100 and M in the order of 300. The real application will also involve a static lookup table, but the size of that depends on the user. It might typically be in the order of 100x100

Comment: @talonmies that might be true, but this code fails to compile at the "processArr(A[i], B[i])" line because obviously nesting the functions like how I am doing is not the right way, but I'm not sure what the right way is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this with Numba

Yes.  What you are wanting to do is a segmented (or vectorized) transform-reduce operation.  The thing that you are calling `processArr` is effectively your transform operation.

To perform multiple parallel segmented reduce operations, there are a number of methods, the "best" of which will depend on the specific sizes of `N` and `M`.

For your choice of `N ~= 100`, I will suggest the use of a CUDA block per reduction.  We will perform a [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) but at the CUDA block level, and each block will be responsible for one result element.  Therefore each block must process `N` elements, and we must launch a total number of blocks equal to `M`.  For the block level processing, we will implement a block-stride loop which is conceptually similar to a [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Here is an example, roughly based on what you have shown:

```
$ cat t47.py
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

# must be power of 2, less than 1025
nTPB = 128

reduce_init_val = 0

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def reduce_op(x,y):
    return x+y

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def transform_op(x,y):
    return x*y

@cuda.jit
def transform_reduce(A, B, C):
    s = cuda.shared.array(nTPB, dtype=A.dtype)
    b = cuda.blockIdx.x
    t = cuda.threadIdx.x
    if (b < A.shape[0]):
        s[t] = reduce_init_val
        #block-stride loop
        for i in range(t, A.shape[1], nTPB):
            s[t] = reduce_op(s[t], transform_op(A[b,i], B[b]))
        #parallel sweep reduction
        l = nTPB//2
        while (l > 0):
            cuda.syncthreads()
            if  (t < l):
                s[t] = reduce_op(s[t], s[t+l])
            l = l//2
        if (t == 0):
            C[b] = s[0]

a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]], dtype=np.float64)
b = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
c = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float64)

threadsperblock = nTPB
blockspergrid = a.shape[0]
transform_reduce[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](a, b, c)
print(c)
$ python t47.py
[0. 4. 9.]
$
```

I'm not suggesting the above code is defect-free or suitable for any particular purpose.  My intent is to outline a possible method.  Note that the above code should be able to handle more-or less arbitrary `M` and `N` dimensions.

Comment: Is there a performance advantage to using the block-stride loop approach in the case where A.shape[1] is guaranteed to be smaller than 1025 so that nTPB can be made large enough to avoid needing to do strides?

Comment: The performance difference should be relatively small if you have enough blocks to saturate the GPU.  If you do not have enough blocks to saturate the GPU, then yes, you would want to make `nTPB` as large as possible, for best performance (but no greater than 1024).  And the performance benefit here would only accrue if the underlying per-block reduction data size is at least that large.  If you are reducing 512 items per block, there is no benefit beyond `nTPB` of 512.  Regardless of these considerations, I would still employ the block-stride loop.  It should not "cost" any performance.